# MySQL Database filesystem standard

Tags: mysql

Our client is asking some document regarding MySQL database filesystem best practices, could you please share information about that.

Comment: The question needs to be more detailed. What do you mean by "filesystem best practises"? Choice of filesystem? Filesystem specific settings? More general settings? Where to locate parts of mysql and its data on your filesystems? ... ... ...

Comment: Where to locate parts of mysql and its data on your filesystems?

Comment: You should edit the extra information into your question using the "edit" link just under the tag list - extra information added as comments can get disconnected from the main body of the question if there are enough comments that not all are displayed. Also indicating the OS that you are using might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB recommends XFS in official docs. But MariaDB (and MySQL have no file system best practises/parameter tuning).

Quote from [What is the best Linux filesystem for MariaDB?](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/what-best-linux-filesystem-mariadb)

> Trying to figure out which filesystem gives the best performance may
>   be fun, but the filesystem won't make a large difference in the
>   performance of your MariaDB server. Your hardware is the most crucial
>   factor in eking out the most speed. Fast hard drives, discrete drive
>   controllers, lots of fast RAM, a multi-core processor, and a fast
>   network have a larger impact on performance than the filesystem. You
>   can also tailor your MariaDB configuration options for best
>   performance for your workloads.

Don't forget to mount fs with `noatime`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the paths of various MySQL Files location in Unix system:

Program : /usr/bin/mysql
Init Script : /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql
Conf : /etc/my.cnf, /root/.my.cnf
Data directory – /var/lib/mysql – Where all databases are stored.
Database naming convention – username_dbname (eg: john_sales)
Permissions on databases – drwx 2 mysql mysql
Socket file – /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock,/tmp/ mysql.sock

Comment: Some of those are controlled by `VARIABLE` settings.